# Trigger after insert to check and compare records between table

Tags: sql, oracle

In an Oracle Database, I need to create some trigger or procedure to treat this case in the most performative way possible (is an extremely large amount of data).

I have a table called `ORDER_A` that every day receives a full load (its truncated, and all records are inserted again).
I have a table called `ORDER_B` which is a copy of `ORDER_A`, containing the same data and some additional control dates.
Each insertion on `ORDER_A` must trigger a process that looks for a record with the same identifier (primary key: order_id) in table `B`.

- If a record exists with the same order_id, and any of the other columns have changed, an update must be performed on table `B`
- If a record exists with the same order_id, and no values ​​in the other columns have been modified, nothing should be performed, the record must remain the same in table `B`.
- If there is no record with the same order_id, it must be inserted in table `B`.

My tables are like this

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_A
(
    ORDER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ORDER_CODE VARCHAR2(50),
    ORDER_STATUS VARCHAR2(20),
    ORDER_USER_ID NUMBER,
    ORDER_DATE TIMESTAMP(6),
    PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER_B
(
    ORDER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ORDER_CODE VARCHAR2(50),
    ORDER_STATUS VARCHAR2(20),
    ORDER_USER_ID NUMBER,
    ORDER_DATE TIMESTAMP(6)
    INSERT_AT TIMESTAMP(6),
    UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP(6),
    PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID)
);
```

I have no idea how to do this and what is the best way (with a trigger, procedure, using merge, etc.)
Can someone give me a direction, please?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some pseudo-code to show you a potential trigger based solution that does not fall back into slow row-by-row processing.

```
create or replace trigger mytrg
  for insert or update delete on ordera
  compound trigger

  pklist sys.odcinumberlist; 
 
  before statement is
  begin
    pklist := sys.odcinumberlist();
  end before statement ;
  
  after each row is
  begin
    pklist.extend;
    pklist(pklist.count) := :new.order_id;
  end before each row;

  after statement is
  begin
    merge into orderb b
    using ( 
      select a.*
      from   ordera a,
             table(pklist) t
      where  a.order_id = t.column_value
    ) m
    when matched then
      update
        set b.order_code = m.order_code,
            b.order_status = m.order_status,
            ...
      where decode(b.order_code,m.order_code,0,1)=1
       or   decode(b.order_status,m.order_status,0,1)=1
       ....
    when not matched then
      insert (b.order_id,b.order_code,....)
      values (m.order_id,m.order_code,....);
      
  end after statement ;

end;
```

We hold the impacted primary keys, and then build a single merge later, with an WHERE embed to minimise update activities.

If your application allows the *update* of primary keys, you'd need some additions, but this should get you started

Comment: Hi Connor, thank you very much for your help!
I'm trying to implement as you suggested, but i'm adding a checksum column in order_b to use as parameter to update or insert. I hope works that way. Best